# Will the integral still be 1?

Tags: calculus, integration, lebesgue-integral

We can show that $\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{e^{-\frac{(x-m)^2}{2}}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}=1$. The easiest way is by observing that this is the probability density of a normal random variable, with mean m, and variance 1.

But what happens if we change m with im, where i is the imaginary number $\sqrt{-1}$. Is the integral still always 1 then?

Comment: Do you know some complex analysis? The identity theorem?

Comment: @DanielFischer After reading on Wikipedia I see that I have seen that theorem before yes. That if two holomorphic functions are defined on a conncted open set, and if they agree on a  non-empty nbh. on that set, they agree on the entire set.

Comment: We have the stronger fact that if they agree on a set that has an accumulation point in the domain they are equal. Now it remains to see that $$f(z) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \exp \biggl(-\frac{(x-z)^2}{2}\biggr)dx$$ is an entire function.

Comment: Note that the result also follows from the fact that $e^{-x^2/2}$ is its own Fourier transform (for the appropriate choice of Fourier transform) without complex analysis.

Comment: @DanielFischerI am trying to show that the function is entire. To show that it is differentiable I end up with a limit of an integral, inside the integral we have a quotient. I am in some way trying to use the dominated convergence theorem. if $h_n$ is a complex series that goes to 0. I have $\int\frac{exp-(x-z-h_n)^2/2-exp-(x-z)^2/2}{h_n}dx$, but I struggle to find a dominating funciton. I am thinking using that $exp-(x-z)^2$ is holomorphic so its derivative must be continuous, and then look at a compact circle around z, and find the max, but this will depend on x.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the integral will still be $1$. One can see that $f\colon \mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}$ defined by

$$f(z) := \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \exp \biggl(-\frac{(x-z)^2}{2}\biggr)dx$$

is constant in various ways.

First of course one has to check that $f$ is well-defined. For $\lvert z\rvert \leqslant K$, one can bound the modulus of the integrand by a function $C_K\cdot e^{-\frac{x^2}{4}}$ (see below), so not only is $f$ well-defined, by the dominated convergence theorem it is also continuous.

One can also use the dominated convergence theorem to see that $f$ is (arbitrarily often) differentiable and differentiation under the integral is legitimate, but the more idiomatic way to show that $f$ is actually holomorphic is using Morera's theorem. For any triangle $\Delta \subset \mathbb{C}$, we have

$$\int_{\partial \Delta} f(z)\,dz = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{\mathbb{R}} \int_{\partial \Delta} \exp \biggl(-\frac{(x-z)^2}{2}\biggr)\,dz \,dx = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{\mathbb{R}} 0\,dx = 0,$$

where the change of order of integration is justified by Fubini's theorem together with the bound from above, and the inner integral over $\partial \Delta$ vanishes by Cauchy's integral theorem. Hence, by Morera's theorem $f$ is holomorphic.

Now the identity theorem together with $f\lvert_{\mathbb{R}} \equiv 1$ shows that $f(z) = 1$ for all $z\in \mathbb{C}$.

One can also use the Fourier transformation to show $f \equiv 1$ by real methods. The key is that $g(x) := e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}$ is a fixed point of the Fourier transform - when one uses the

$$\mathscr{F}[h](\omega) := \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{\mathbb{R}} h(x) e^{-ix\omega}\,dx$$

variant of the Fourier transform. For other variants the Fourier transform is still a function of the form $e^{-\alpha x^2}$ for some $\alpha > 0$ and some details in the computation change, but the basic structure is the same.

We recall that for the translates $\tau_y h \colon x \mapsto h(x-y)$, we have

$$\mathscr{F}[\tau_y h](\omega) = e^{-iy\omega}\mathscr{F}[h](\omega),$$

and thus with $z = u+iv$ we have

\begin{align}
f(z) &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{\mathbb{R}} \exp\biggl(-\frac{\bigl((x-u) - iv\bigr)^2}{2}\biggr) dx\\
&= \frac{e^{\frac{v^2}{2}}}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \exp\biggl(-\frac{(x-u)^2}{2}\biggr) e^{i(x-u)v}\,dx\\
&= e^{\frac{v^2}{2}-iuv}\mathscr{F}[\tau_u g](-v)\\
&= e^{\frac{v^2}{2}-iuv}\cdot e^{-iu(-v)}e^{-\frac{(-v)^2}{2}}\\
&= 1.
\end{align}

---

To show that for every $K\in (0,+\infty)$ there is a $C_K\in (0,+\infty)$ such that

$$\biggl\lvert \exp \biggl(-\frac{(x-z)^2}{2}\biggr)\biggr\rvert \leqslant C_k\cdot e^{-\frac{x^2}{4}}$$

for all $z$ with $\lvert z\rvert \leqslant K$, we use the elementary inequality $\lvert e^w\rvert \leqslant e^{\lvert w\rvert}$ for $w\in \mathbb{C}$ and the addition theorem of the exponential function. For $\lvert x\rvert \geqslant 4K$ we have $\lvert z\rvert \leqslant K \leqslant \frac{1}{4}\lvert x\rvert$, and hence $\lvert xz\rvert \leqslant \frac{x^2}{4}$, so

$$\biggl\lvert \exp \biggl(-\frac{(x-z)^2}{2}\biggr)\biggr\rvert \leqslant e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}\cdot e^{\lvert zx\rvert}\cdot e^{\frac{\lvert z\rvert^2}{2}} \leqslant e^{\frac{K^2}{2}}\cdot e^{-\frac{x^2}{4}}.$$

On the compact set $[-4K,4K]$ the continuous function

$$e^{\frac{x^2}{4}}\biggl\lvert \exp \biggl(-\frac{(x-z)^2}{2}\biggr)\biggr\rvert$$

is bounded, say by $B_K$, and then we can choose $C_K = \max \bigl\{B_K, e^{\frac{K^2}{2}}\bigr\}$.